# Match Substring with spaces in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to match a sub-string with a given string in perl.

Match is failing when the sub-string contains space.

Example:

Please consider the following string variable:

```
var = "test [abc], def, xyz,"
```

The expression:

```
($var=~ m/test [abc]/)
```

doesn't return 1.

Strings without spaces are working fine:

```
Example:

($var=~ m/def/)

is returning 1.
```

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[` and `]` in regex have special meaning. They define character classes. If you want to match a `[` or a `]`, you need to escape them:

```
$var=~ m/test \[abc\]/
```

Comment: Thanks. Here I have used 'real strings' for example purpose. What shall I do if "test [abc]" is also contained in a variable?

Comment: For example: ($var=~ m/$some_var/), where some_var is "test [abc]" or any other string

Comment: @SandeepSingh You can use quoting sequences: `$var=~ m/\Q$some_var\E/` That way, you will match the value of `$some_var` literally.

Answer (score 2):

`[]` are character class in regex. you have to escape those:

```
($var=~ m/test \[abc\]/)
```

In your example `test [abc]` will match `test a`, `test b` or `test c`. Cause `[abc]` means any of `a,b,c`

Comment: Thanks, but what to do in case - both LHS & RHS contains variables: ($var=~ m/$some_var/), where some_var is "test [abc]" or any other string

Comment: Escape the `[]` inside the variable `$some_var` first. Then use it in regex.